# This is my doorbell transformer, right?

Tags: electrical, wiring, doorbell

Before I screw something up, I just want to verify that I’ve identified the right thing. I’m putting in a new transformer for my doorbell as my [Ring Video Doorbell 3 Plus](https://support.ring.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040748431-Download-the-Manual-Ring-Video-Doorbell-3-Plus) is no longer charging correctly and the existing stuff is old. Here’s what I have:
[image: Transformer]

[image: Not transformer]

This first thing is mounted on the side of my circuit breaker panel. I’m pretty sure that’s the transformer. The second thing is the chime (still going strong since December of 1959!). It is my assumption that the thing in the first picture must be swapped out, and nothing in the second picture needs to be modified. Am I correct?

Comment: It's also possible that the red and white wire are (semi-) shorting at the door bel. Straighten them out. And while you're at it, clean out the dust, and follow the service instructions. Maybe it's just that easy.

Comment: @P2000 At the doorbell, yes. But the chime "is still going strong".

Comment: @MikeWaters yes I like your answer, which is why I only commented. OP should still straighten out those wires. And I'm not sure what is meant with "Ring is no longer charging". Is there also a "Ring" video doorbell somewhere? If so, where is it wired? Is OP keeping the old chime with the Ring?

Comment: @P2000 Sorry if it wasn’t clear; yeah, I have a video doorbell 3 plus, hardwired to the wires that were in the house when I bought it. The original chime and transformer have worked fine for a long while, but now it’s acting like there’s no power source to charge the battery.

Comment: I haven't installed a ring, but I take it you connected it to the switch wires at the door, right? And you removed the old switch? So the Ring is charging *through* the old chime. What's the voltage at the Ring terminals while charging? Is the old chime still in operation with the ring? Do you have all four wires (2 from transformer, 2 to chime) available at the switch?

Comment: @P2000 Yes, I removed the old switch a couple of years ago and connected the Ring. The button on the Ring now activates the existing chime, and, until this week, those wires also continuously charged the Ring’s battery. This week, the status in the app changed to indicate it was no longer hardwired, but running off battery, and after a few days, it drained the battery and died. At the time I installed it, I measured adequate voltage on the wires at the door, though I don’t recall the configuration or number of wires and am hoping to avoid pulling it off for a look.

Comment: At this point I have a suspicion that the Ring is failing, possibly its rechargeable battery. If you connect the wires at the switch (like the old switch did), does the chime work snappy and clear? If so, it's not the transformer, but likely the Ring or its battery.

Comment: @P2000 Hmmm. Yeah, I’m starting to think it’s the battery, too.

Comment: Aside - if you do remove this vintage doorbell, do not dispose of it.  These kind of things go well on ebay/etc and if you don't want to do that, give it to someone who will.

Comment: @Criggie Good to know, though I think if I were to remove it, I’d probably clean it up and put it into a glass display case. It is a beaut’ and a relic!

Answer (score 6):

The first item is *definitely* a transformer. We can tell that by its core laminations and its appearance.

And it is almost certain that the transformer is a doorbell transformer. (It *might* be a furnace transformer.)

Can you measure the AC voltage on both the 120 volt primary (to see if it's getting power)? If so, measure the AC voltage at the low-voltage secondary, the two screws where the two wires are attached. You should see a voltage a little less than 30 volts.

The second item is a doorbell.

---

The fact that the chime still works tells me that the doorbell transformer is fine. You should still measure the transformer voltage to be sure.

---

How do you know for certain that your Ring is connected to it?

Comment: Mike, do you perhaps know why not to oil the striker, but naphta is ok?

Comment: Note that the transformer could be a furnace transformer.  Usually these are attached to the furnace, but not always.

Comment: @P2000 The viscosity of oil inhibits the movement of the strikers, and it might not make any sound. Naphtha, etc. is a solvent, cleaning off any contaminants that prevent their free movement.

Comment: @HotLicks Thank you, edited my answer to include that possibility.

Comment: I tested the 2 screws on that transformer. I got about 14v which I think is a little less than what the Ring needs. I am not sure how to access the 120v side of that thing. I suppose I need to open the panel, just as I would of replacing it?

Comment: Updates... I pulled the Ring off the exterior wall of my house and tested the wires that it uses.  They are getting 14.4v.  There are only two wires; a hot and neutral, methinks?  I cleaned up the wires and terminals on the chime, as suggeted by @P2000.  I have verified the transformer in my picture is connected to the doorbell, not a furnace or anything else.  I'm not sure if the 14.4v is just not enough, or if maybe this doorbell is just going bad, or what.

Comment: @MikeWaters, I forgot to answer you about how I know the Ring is connected... it has been connected and operating perfectly for a long time now.  It both operates the chime, and uses the voltage to keep the battery charged.  Having changed nothing, this week, it began to show as no longer hardwired, and the battery began to dip, eventually getting so low that the doorbell went offline.

Comment: @bubbleking, Yes you will need to take the face off of your electric panel to access the 120V side of the transformer and to remove the nut holding it in place.  Turn off the main breaker first (or power going to the panel if possible).  If the main breaker is the only way to turn off the power, be aware that the big wires coming into the panel and the lugs they are connected to will always be live and deadly.  Should be easy to avoid them, but be aware of what you are dealing with.